# "Out of gas" revert inside the multisend contract

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I got the refundReceiver working (had been passing the separate transactions into the encodeMulti function instead of the array of transactions into createTransaction) but I get an "out of gas" revert inside the multisend contract no matter what combination of params I seem to use inside createTransaction and executeTransaction are. I guess I am still confused about which params to use inside createTransaction and executeTransaction functions. At this point the transactions I want to execute aren't happening. I would like to get that working and also reimburse the signer the exact amount of the gas fee for the transaction they are executing.

There is a delegate call to the multisend contract that seems to have a gas limit set at 0 no matter what I have tried:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x72a6491ff9dc8294d14620c41e4baa25b5b3d0e5c0929b3ce7cbe1008dfe50e0#internal

```
  const txOptions = {
    gasPrice: getGasPrice,
    gasToken: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    refundReceiver: signer.address,
    safeTxGas: 1000000,
    baseGas: 1000000,
    gasLimit: 10000000,
  };
  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(
    multiSendTx,
    txOptions
  );

  const execOptions = {
    gasLimit: 10000000,
  };

  const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(
    safeTransaction,
    execOptions
  );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the transaction you linked, the `safeTxGas` param is 0, and so it passes 0 gas to the underlying transaction. Therefore, you need to specify the correct amount of gas for the underlying transaction via the `safeTxGas` param when using a gas refund.

For the particular snippet, you need to move `safeTxGas` to the options object because when you pass an array of transactions for multisend it expects it to be in the second `options` parameter.

Check docs for `multisend transactions` section:
https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/63df6c6c770f387f8e4939c4c75112ceb490b3b8/packages/safe-core-sdk

Comment: But `safeTxGas` is specified, why is it not taken?

Comment: good catch, updated the answer

Comment: According to https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/63df6c6c770f387f8e4939c4c75112ceb490b3b8/packages/safe-core-sdk#createtransaction it is already in the correct place (assuming multiSendTx is an array of txs)

Comment: If you look at etherscan you can also see that the other params are correctly applied, just safeTxGas is 0

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread the code, then no idea. It should be taken into account. It'd help if we could check the full snippet and try to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue. Looks like there's an issue with the `safe-core-sdk` on github which is likely causing `SafeTxGas` to be 0 regardless of what it is in options.

https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/issues/139